# ThreeJS Cut the corners of the depth of an ExtrudeGeometry shape

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I have a **3D shape (THREE.Shape)** created in **Threejs** by using some vertices.Then I use **ExtrudeGeometry** to make it 3D looking shape. I need this **shape with edges cut in 45 degrees**. But the main problem is I have to **cut the edges of the extrude part of geometry**. I am not enable to find any single solution of this anywhere.
I would try my best to make you understand the real requirement.

[image: This is a simple shape with face and extrude part]

I want to **cut the edges of the Extrude part not of the face**. You can see the below image for reference

[image: I need edges cut with 45 degrees like this]

so remember this is not the face of shape. Simple shape without extrude part looks like this

[image: Simple image without ExtrudeGeometry]

Anyone who can help me in the solution of this? It would be really appreciating for him if he can help me in sort out the solution for this.

Comment: The conception of 45 degrees is an isosceles right triangle, that I provided in my answer. This is from a school geometry course.

Answer (score 0):

An option of how you can do it:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 20);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var w = 1;
var h = 3;
var d = 10;

var pts = [
  new THREE.Vector2(-w, h),
  new THREE.Vector2(-w, -h),
  new THREE.Vector2(w, -w),
  new THREE.Vector2(w, w)
]

var shape = new THREE.Shape(pts);
var shapeGeom = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry(shape, {
  depth: d * 2,
  bevelEnabled: false
});
shapeGeom.center();
shapeGeom.rotateY(-Math.PI * 0.5);

// 45 deg cut
var pos = shapeGeom.getAttribute("position");
var temp = new THREE.Vector3();
for (let i = 0; i < pos.count; i++) {
  temp.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i);
  let signX = Math.sign(temp.x);
  let shift = h - temp.y;
  pos.setX(i, temp.x - (shift * signX));
}
pos.needsUpdate = true;

var shapeMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "aqua",
  wireframe: true
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(shapeGeom, shapeMat);
scene.add(mesh);




renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is still not working good with my shape. Can you download the [vertex data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UQLvcukuA2SZW9rOPWJ0gDUwN_3yOE1D/view?usp=sharing) of my project and try with that? 
You can use vertex in this file to create shape. Once you create shape, you can add depth like 10 in extrude settings and then I want 45 degree curve over there

Comment: @USMANHEART I even don't know what is what in your data, you've provided no code of how to work with it.

Comment: this is my simple [Test Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rtoNvwh5PLzq0Jy5sdR-8OIN9fkUlqZB/view?usp=sharing), you can check it out. There is a function name TestShape. I have only one simple shape added in it. I want that shape edges cut into 45 degrees same as I mentioned